# Want to upload a file in sharepoint library using Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I am looking for a C# code which will upload a document in Sharepoint document library using graph API, please let me know if anyone has implemented this in Past, any Git code path..etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [PnP Core SDK](https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/). This should save you some time, since it already has a lot of code for completing basic actions in SharePoint Online.